# HttpHandlers with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I have a standard AXD HttpHandler and the default ignore route for *.axd, then why is ASP.NET MVC still handling requests in subdirs, for instance if there is a request made for **/Content/Css/**css.axd?d....
If the request is made at root /css.axd?d.... everything works fine.

Comment: You might want to post your route, could be a problem with how you are defining it.

Comment: this is the default ignore route:

            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

Answer (score 6):

I guess the route was deliberately made like that by design, maybe because the wildcard at a start of string isn't as performant.

Unfortunately this won't work:

> routes.IgnoreRoute("{ *pathAndResource }.axd/{ *pathInfo }")

The solution is to use constraints - see [Phil Haack's blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx)

Phil's blogs uses a regular expression constraint, but you could create you own custom contraint alternatively to make things more readable:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("match axds"
 "{*url}", new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction" }, new
              {
                  myCustomConstraint = new FileExtensionConstraint(".axd")
              }
```

Comment: Why is that default IgnoreRoute there then? In every new ASP.NET MVC projects created...

Comment: The default ignore route is needed to support asp.net 2.0's built-in web resources which are always found at: /webresource.axd see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910442.