# Ignore all .axd file from MVC routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my application, Both mvc and web form is present.

But when I open any `.aspx` page then in `Application_Error` error is thrown.

> The controller for path '/WebResource.axd' was not found or does not implement IController.
>
> The controller for path '/ScriptResource.axd' was not found or does
>   not implement IController.

I tried all these method, but none of them is working.

- Added at top in RegisterRoutes method.

  `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
   routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*\.aspx(/.*)?" });`
- Create a FileTypeConstraint class to check file ext.

.

```
public class FileTypeConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        private readonly string[] MatchingFileTypes;

        public FileTypeConstraint(string matchingFileType)
        {
            MatchingFileTypes = new[] { matchingFileType };
        }

        public FileTypeConstraint(string[] matchingFileTypes)
        {
            MatchingFileTypes = matchingFileTypes;
        }

        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            if (values["url"] != null)
            {
                string path = values["url"].ToString();
                return MatchingFileTypes.Any(x => path.ToLower().EndsWith(x, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

And added this line at top and bottom both

```
 routes.MapRoute(
     "Defaultaxd",
      "{*url}",
       new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new { myCustomConstraint = new FileTypeConstraint(new[] { "axd" }) }
          );
```

Tried all these links.

[HttpHandlers with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666211/httphandlers-with-asp-net-mvc)

[ASP.NET MVC routing issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609726/asp-net-mvc-routing-issue)

[Using URL Routing for Web Forms and StopRoutingHandler for Favicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500750/using-url-routing-for-web-forms-and-stoproutinghandler-for-favicon)

Comment: Check out some of the alternative answers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109841/im-getting-a-does-not-implement-icontroller-error-on-images-and-robots-txt-in maybe those work

Comment: @Shogunivar: already checked that link too. None of those method works.